# Strange behavior of JSON.parse() in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with JSON.parse() which is that it always returns an 'unavailable' result. Here is a simple test case:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
      var lnkArr=JSON.parse('{}');
      console.log('lnkArr: ', lnkArr);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

This produces: `lnkArr:  <unavailable>`. It doesn't matter what I parse, the result is the same. There are no related errors and the same code works fine in Chrome. Is there something that I'm doing wrong here or is this a bug?

Also, if someone can point me to information on exactly what 'unavailable' means I'd really appreciate it because everything I can find about this is talking about scope and nothing says anything about scope changing like this.

*Update*

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 48.0a2 (2016-05-19). The fiddle linked to by Martin produces the same results.

Comment: My best guess is that the garbage collector has been faster than the console. Logging objects has always been tricky but I would assume that the log prevents collection.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What version of Firefox are you using? Are you using the built in console, or Firebug?

Comment: What happens in your console here: https://jsfiddle.net/tsym2euz/ I am on firefox/osx and it seems to work fine

Comment: Yep - worked fine for me too in FF

Comment: Related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136995

Comment: When dealing with weird logging issues, sometimes it helps to serialize the item:  `console.log('lnkArr: ', JSON.stringify(lnkArr));`

Comment: @JAAulde I don't think that this is an issue with the console because the variable is actually not available. I found this because this causes a cascade of errors in the rest of my code due to this variable not having a value.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I'm SHOCKED by the results I got from that. I almost didn't bother trying it because I figured that if the variable is unavailable to me it must be unavailable to anything I call. In reality, that produced the expected results, `lnkArr:  {}`. That's good but I really need to data as an object. Any idea on how to use it as such?

Comment: @Bergi I believe your comment is the source of the problem. I just found out that, by using the console that is part of the dev tools, it is actually working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering from the comments:

This is an issue where the console is sometimes not in line with what is actually happening.

Chrome, in particular, is known to run the console is a different thread as the JavaScript code and thus objects can change -- or even be garbage collected -- between the time `console.log` is called and when the results are displayed.

Using JSON.stringify can "copy" the object so that it will log correctly:

```
console.log('lnkArr: ', JSON.stringify(lnkArr));
```

That said, at that moment in time, `lnkArr` is actually an object.  It shows as a string in the console because that is what we asked for -- but that's just for display purposes.

```js
var str = '{"prop": true}';

var o = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
console.log('But `prop` is: ', o.prop);
```